# Algorithm for lattice of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, gap

In spite of my repeated efforts I have not been able to find the algorithm for calculating lattice of subgroups for any group. GAP does it very well but I need algorithm as I am trying to implement things myself as well.

Comment: I believe is is quite easy to access the GAP source code, which should help you. I've added the GAP tag, so that someone more knowledgable than I will clarify this...

Comment: I am starting with symmetric group

Comment: @Blackbird: I think you need using Linux to do XGAP package.

Comment: I have used GAP many times, my idea is to get clear picture of algorithm by implementing it in Mathematica.

Comment: @Blackbird: But is Mathematica enough good and powerful to handle symbolic computational jobs as GAP does? It'll be great if someday, someone does it for Win envirounment.

Comment: Actually using GUI version of linux(which is replica of windows almost) GAP package can be used with ease there is no as such requirement for again putting in effort for other platforms.Mathematica can do anything  when it comes to symbolic.I have programmed in many languages(being a software engineer) but Mathematica is most intelligently written.

Comment: The subgroup lattice source code is commented and more or less follows the paper. I think you'll find there are 40 years of intensive research on this problem, so that you need to be a lot more specific on what sort of algorithm you want.

Comment: I just want to calculate subgroups using lattice method because my other efforts have brought me much closer to finding it but then I cannot go beyond order 5. Moreover I will be able to find other properties using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To compute subgroup lattice of small groups such as $S_6$, you may find that the method of Zuppos is easy to understand, not too hard to implement, and is reasonably quick.

The method is described in [Butler's textbook](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-54955-2_25). It was originally described by Neubüser (1960).

The idea is big subgroups $H$ come from small subgroups $K$. In fact we can require $K \lhd H$ and $[H:K] =p$ (unless $H$ is very special). So we start with $K=1$, and then find all the subgroups of prime order. For each of those, we check which elements of appropriate order normalize $K$, and adjoin them. If $x$ normalizes $K$, then $|\langle x,K\rangle| = |xK| \cdot |K|$, where the first factor $|xK|$ is the order of $x$ mod $K$.

To make this more efficient we precompute a list of zuppos (cyclic subgroups of prime power order), and just figure out which zuppos lie in the group. Subgroups are listed as binary vectors, with the $i$th position's boolean value describing whether the $i$th zuppo is contained in the subgroup.

Implementation details, examples, and discussion are included in the book.

This technique should get you to the symmetric group $S_8$ or so, but you'll need the list of perfect groups (the special $H$ that don't come from a $K$). It is available on microfiche! Also in GAP.

GAP's implementation is line 259 of `lib/grplatt.gi`

- Neubüser, J.
  “Untersuchungen des Untergruppenverbandes endlicher Gruppen auf einer programmgesteuerten electronischen Dualmaschine.”
  Numer. Math. 2 (1960) 280–292.
  MR[117939](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=117939)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01386229](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01386229)
- Butler, G.
  *Fundamental algorithms for permutation groups.*
  Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 559.
  Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1991. xii+238 pp. ISBN: 3-540-54955-2
  MR[1225579](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1225579)
  DOI:[10.1007/3-540-54955-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-54955-2)

Comment: I will work on it first and than I will write my opinion on it. Thanks by the way(+1).